# Can we prove that a point is either in the interior, exterior or boundary of a set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, I am reading Michael Spivak’s book Calculus on Manifolds and when he starts speaking of sets, he states something like this:

If we take an arbitrary set $A$ and an arbitrary point $x$, then either one of three has to be true:

- There exists an open set $B$ such that $x\in B\subset A$
- There exists an open set $B$ such that $x\in B \subset \overline A$
- For all open sets $B$ such that $x\in B$, $B$ contains elements of $A$ and $\overline A$

My question is: Can we prove this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the three conditions a, b, c.

For any set $A$, either c holds, and we're done, or c does not hold.

In the latter case (c does *not* hold), there's some open set $B$ containing $x$ that either contains *only* elements of $A$ (which is "a") or contains only elements of $\bar{A}$ (which is case "b").

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do we even know that there are points satisfying c?

Comment: We **don't** know that, and Spivak doesn't claim that, which is a good thing, because it's false. If, for instance, we're working in $\Bbb R$, and $A = \Bbb R$, then there are no points satisfying either b or c, but the statement that every point satisfies **exactly one** of the three is still true: they all satisfy the first one!

Comment: Hmm ok, I got it. Thank you